# jQuery click action only fires once, per page refresh

Tags: jquery

I have written a jQuery code in the admin section of my site that turns the site offline without page refresh. It works great, but for one thing:

> When I click on TURN ON the ajax call is made accurately and all the classes are changed and the text is changed the TURN OFF. However, when I click on this text, nothing happens. If I reload the page, then I will be able to.

```
$("#switch_off").click(function() {
                $("#switch_off").html("<img style=\"padding-left:15px;\" src=\"/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif\">");
                $('#switch_off').removeClass('ttip_b')
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/settings/SwitchOffline",
                    type: "get",
                    data: '',
                    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){ // Trigger when request was successful
                        $("#site_status").html("<span id=\"offline\" class=\"lbl error_bg\">Offline</span><span id=\"switch_on\" class=\"ttip_b\" title=\"Click to place Site Online\">Turn On</span>");
                    },
                    error: function(responseText){
                        //alert(responseText);
                    }   
                });
                return false;
            });

            $("#switch_on").click(function() {
                $("#switch_on").html("<img style=\"padding-left:15px;\" src=\"/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif\">");
                $('#switch_on').removeClass('ttip_b')
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/settings/SwitchOnline",
                    type: "get",
                    data: '',
                    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){                            
                        $("#site_status").html("<span id=\"online\" class=\"lbl ok_bg\">Online</span><span id=\"switch_off\" class=\"ttip_b\" title=\"Click to place Site Offline\">Turn Off</span>");                          
                    },
                    error: function(responseText){
                        //alert(responseText);
                    }   
                });

                return false;
            });
```

[image: ONLINE]
[image: OFFLINE]

HTML CODE WITH SOME PHP

```
<div class="user_info user_sep" style="width:90px;">
                            <p class="sepH_a">
                                <strong>Site Status</strong>
                            </p>
                            <?php
                            //debug($site_offline);
                            if($site_offline){
                            ?>                              
                            <span id="site_status">
                                <span id="offline" class="lbl error_bg">Offline</span>
                                <span id="switch_on" class="ttip_b" title="Click to place Site Online">Turn On</span>

                            </span>
                            <?php }else{ ?>
                            <span id="site_status">
                                <span id="online" class="lbl ok_bg">Online</span>
                                <span id="switch_off" class="ttip_b" title="Click to place Site Offline">Turn Off</span>

                            </span>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: First, it's better to use toggle for such things. Second, can't you show us html of your code? or perhaps you can show us a live demo on jsFiddle?

Comment: i replicated it ur right turn off doesnt work i will check why now

Comment: i think i have enough info join me in CHAT then when we arrive at answer together i post it as answer: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22281/onandoff

Comment: you have to bind the action to the new text element i will post u a solution now soon.

Comment: i have your answer but theres something really simple im missing can u join my chat ill show u the solution i made for you we can find out how to make it work.

Comment: DID IT answer coming really soon

Comment: there were quite a few problems with your code 1) your code makes the page have duplicate ids 2) when you get the ajax result, you did absolutely nothing else! You actually need to bind the result to the function to turn it on or off! --- So I made a solution for you which fixes these things and now clicking the text received from ajax will actually work.

Comment: I updated my answer if you didn't like my original. I'm not sure who downvoted my answer.

Comment: SAJAWIKIO... I didnt down vote your answer. I will the solutions now to see what works... thanks to all

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using event delegation instead because you are rewriting the HTML on every click and the bindings are being lost. By making use of event delegation you are binding the event for present elements in the DOM and future ones that will be appended to the DOM such as those ones resulting from your AJAX calls.

Use

```
$("#site_status").on("click", "#switch_off", function() {
  ...
});
```

```
$("#site_status").on("click", "#switch_on", function() {
  ...
});
```

instead of

```
$("#switch_off").click(function() {
  ...
});
```

```
$("#switch_on").click(function() {
  ...
});
```

If `#site_status` is also being overwritten then use `document`.

Comment: Thank you Alexander for the quick and accurate answer. Excellent!

Comment: I used "document" instead of "#site_status"

Answer (score 11):

To expand on @Alexander's answer, the problem is that you're dynamically generating HTML content, but adding listeners on document initialization.  This means that some of the elements you're attempting to bind to **don't exist yet** at the time of binding.  Thus the listeners are never created.  The solution is to use jQuery [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to "listen" for events on elements that don't exist yet:

```
$("#switch_off").click(function() {
```

Should be:

```
$(document).on('click', '#switch_off', function() {
```

And similarly:

```
$("#switch_on").click(function() {
```

Should be:

```
$(document).on('click', '#switch_on', function() {
```

However, as others have expressed, a better solution would be to clean up the code a bit and show/hide the respective states vs generating them on the fly.

Comment: Excellent solution. It works perfectly. I hadn't thought about hide/show solution, but I will consider it on my future coding. Thanks alot....

Comment: Hey, if you thought that I needed to elaborate more on my answer, then I would have prefered to do the expanding myself. Don't forget you also can comment on other's people answers

Comment: True... and it would be fair as you answered first. The problem is that when I came back to the question, Rohler was the first I saw and since it work just fine, I did not look into the other ones with as much attention as I should have.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work in your case:

**EDIT**: IF YOU WANT ONLY ONE BUTTON (it seems like this is what you want upon rereading your question) - the following code works. By the way the only way I can think of in your scenario (and for this demo's purposes) is to just start out as "off", otherwise you need to come up with your own ajax to "check" the status of whether server is ON or OFF and then to put the appropriate code in the HTML (and the appropriate initiating JS). I leave that up to you to figure out. I have an idea how to do that too, but that's for you to decide if you want or not.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ytpv7/11/

HTML:

```
<div id="site_status"><span id='switch_on'> Offline Turn ON  </span></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#switch_on").click(ON);


function ON() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/settings/SwitchOnline",
        type : "get",
        data : '',
        complete : function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            var str = "<span id='switch_off'>" + 'Online Turn OFF' + "</span>";
      $("#site_status").html(str);
            $("#switch_off").click(OFF);
        },
        error : function (responseText) {
            //alert(responseText);
        }
    });

    return false;
}

function OFF() {

    $.ajax({
        url : "/settings/SwitchOffline",
        type : "get",
        data : '',
        complete : function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            var str = "<span id='switch_on'>" + "Offline Turn ON" + "</span>";
      $("#site_status").html(str);
            $("#switch_on").click(ON);
        },
        error : function (responseText) {
            //alert(responseText);
      }
    });
    return false;
}
```

**END EDIT**

ORIGINAL ANSWER - with ON and OFF button (with ajax-resultant text also working):

(note in JSFIDDLE that for demonstration purposes I changed ajax event to on complete -  you change it back to success for your purposes)

http://jsfiddle.net/ytpv7/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="switch_off">OFF</div>
<div id="switch_on">ON</div>
<div id="site_status"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#switch_off").click(OFF);

$("#switch_on").click(ON);

function ON() {
    $("#switch_on").html("<img style=\"padding-left:15px;\" src=\"/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif\">");
    $('#switch_on').removeClass('ttip_b');
    $.ajax({
        url : "/settings/SwitchOnline",
        type : "get",
        data : '',
        complete : function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            var str = "<span id='online'>" + 'Online Turn OFF' + "</span>";
      $("#site_status").html(str);
            $("#online").click(OFF);
        },
        error : function (responseText) {
            //alert(responseText);
        }
    });

    return false;
}

function OFF() {
    $("#switch_off").html("<img style=\"padding-left:15px;\" src=\"/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif\">");
    $('#switch_off').removeClass('ttip_b')
    $.ajax({
        url : "/settings/SwitchOffline",
        type : "get",
        data : '',
        complete : function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) { // Trigger when request was successful
            var str = "<span id='offline'>" + "Offline Turn ON" + "</span>";
      $("#site_status").html(str);
            $("#offline").click(ON);
        },
        error : function (responseText) {
            //alert(responseText);
      }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I thought Alexander's answer was more straight forward and easier to implement. Thanks for your efforts...